# custom field meta-box with dropdown/autocomplete

Tags: php, custom-field, metabox, dropdown, autocomplete

Is it possible to have a custom metabox with the ability to either:

- enter a new meta_value in a certain meta_key
  OR
- choose from a list of the existing meta_keys, from a dropdown/select-box, autocomplete/suggestions or anything else

(basically, the way category and tag meta-boxes work, only with custom fields not custom taxonomies)

Graphically, the box should look like this: [image: metabox example]

Can this be done with an existing plugin or code / how?

Comment: Yes it is possible. What have you tried already?

Comment: I tried practically all meta-box plug-ins, none has it but maybe I missed one. I can also do a simple meta-box add field manually, but I have no idea where to start for populating the select :(

Comment: Just found that the plugins Magic Fields 2 (https://wordpress.org/plugins/magic-fields-2/) together with Magic Fields 2 Toolkit (https://wordpress.org/plugins/magic-fields-2-toolkit/) can technically do the job, but the formatting is weird and the functionality quirky, so many users would have trouble getting it to work.

Comment: Code, I asked about what code have you tried. This site is about development, not about use third party software

Comment: Don't let me waste your time, I'll figure it out somehow and post the answer myself when I have it.